# Conditionally display open tracking pixel for CC/BCC email addresses

Tags: marketing-cloud, email

Someone asked me how to conditionally display the email open tracking pixel when sent to a CC/BCC email address (on an account where the CC/BCC feature is enabled).

They have a process that is opening and storing BCC emails, and when this occurs, Marketing Cloud is recording the email as an 'open' (even though the Subscriber did not open the email).

I note that the CC/BCC email is an exact copy, that is the system personalization string `emailaddr` returns the Subscriber's email address, so you can't conditionally display the open tracking pixel for CC/BCC recipients. Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only workaround that I've come up with is to suppress the click domain on the machine that is opening the CC/BCC email addresses. This can either be implemented by a local firewall rule, or [editing the hosts file](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27350/beginner-geek-how-to-edit-your-hosts-file/) on the machine.

For example, add the following entry to the hosts file on the machine that is opening the emails:

```
0.0.0.0    click.subdomain.mydomain.com
```

Where `subdomain.mydomain.com` is the SAP domain of the Marketing Cloud account. This will block the click domain (used to track email opens) so emails will not be recorded as an open.